# Python statsmodels GAM: How to choose penalties?

Tags: python, statsmodels, gam

I am wondering how to choose the penalties resp. the alpha using GAM with statsmodels.
The documentation of statsmodels gam states:

> The alpha above are from the unit tests against the R mgcv package.

So does that mean there is no python/statsmodels way to choose the penalties/alpha? If I need R mgcv for that, then I'd use R right away, but I'd like to implement my model in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAM in statsmodels has two methods to select the penalization weights in the Model class

The first uses information criteria like aic, bic or gcv
https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.gam.generalized_additive_model.GLMGam.select_penweight.html

The second uses k-fold cross validation
https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.gam.generalized_additive_model.GLMGam.select_penweight_kfold.html

The usage is shown at the end of the documentation example
https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/gam.html

Comment: Thanks Josef! I saw those two methods, but I was confused that the documentation example would use alpha from R mgcv rather than the own methods.

Secondly, I don't quite understand how to use these methods. In the example we apply the method "select_penweight()" to the GLMGam gam_bs. But gam_bs already is fitted with the alpha from R mgcv! How do I use those methods without using R mgcv. I only want to use python.

Comment: First you create a model with an arbitrary penweight, then use a select_penweight method to find some optimal penalization weight and then create a new model instance with the selected penweight. Creating a new model instance is safer, so that there is not the wrong penweight attached. This could still change.

Comment: Edit: Could you maybe add this to your answer?
I guess it would be clearer if this approach would be included in the documentation, but maybe it will added later, thanks! I just wanted to note here that i could replicate the correct penalties for the second model (the one that adds "family=sm.families.Poisson()"), but not for the first model (the one without poisson distribution), which is unfortunate. It doesn't seem to be robust.
Also I don't quite understand the huge difference in the output of select_penweight and select_penweight_kfold. But I guess this is not the place to discuss this.